# Apex ternary operator - Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be a statement

Tags: apex, ternary-operator

Trying to simplify multifle if-else conditions . Below code is throwing error " Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be a statement. " . Can you please let me know how to resolve the issue ?

```
 if (hasFailedBatches) {
   Boolean inDMode = run.Run_Mode__c == 'inDMode' ? true:false;
   inDMode ? input.put('Status', 'Failed'):input.put('Status', 'Retrival fialed');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While:

```
inDMode ? input.put('Status', 'Failed'):input.put('Status', 'Retrival fialed');
```

is legal in JavaScript and other languages, you can't do this in Apex. Instead, you can use the ternary operator as a parameter:

```
input.put(
  'Status', 
  inDMode? 'Failed', 'Retrieval Failed'
);
```

### Other Notes

You can also use a ternary operator with a compatible set of data types, such as:

```
(isInput? inputMap: outputMap).put('key','value');
```

And it's also legal for functions as long as they return the same type:

```
someVar = someBoolean? functionA(): functionB();
```

Note that a Boolean operator already returns a Boolean:

```
Boolean inDMode = run.Run_Mode__c == 'inDMode';
```

Comment: Thank you so much . You are one of the best salesforce expert .